# Formula/regex to remove/replace everything except number(id) in google sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, string-matching

I have ~20k rows like:

```
/CNTI=1/USERID=1/ACCTNUM=1/USERTYPE=1/NUMLISTS=0/ASTATUS=0x0        
/CNTI=1/USERID=2/ACCTNUM=5/USERTYPE=3/NUMLISTS=120/ASTATUS=0x0
/CNTI=1/USERID=321/ACCTNUM=6/USERTYPE=1/NUMLISTS=0/ASTATUS=0x0
```

What I'm trying to do is to remove everything and leave only the ID number. In the example above - `1`,`2`, `321`...

I have tried with regex on google sheet -> Find and Replace -> Search with regex and I have searched for `/CNTI=*/` in order to delete firs all `CNTI`'s then ACCTNUM and so on but the function says that the search term isn't found. Tried also `/CNTI=~/`, `/CNTI=*?/` still not found.

Can someone help with formula or proper regex which I can use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(IF(A1:A="";;IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A; "USERID=(\d+)"))*1))
```

[image]

Comment: One addition question - can I copy/paste the result now? Because when I try to do it the clean ID's are disheartening and got blank column

Comment: @Goro sure. use CTRL+C then CTRL+SHIFT+V